# How to properly share code between applications in a django project

Tags: python, django

I have several applications in my django project. I would like to re-use some of the functions across all of my apps. I created a new app, and added a custom functions.py to it. Trying the following:

```
from myNewApp import *
from myNewApp import functions
```

I get NameError: global name xxx is undefined

Am I omitting something important?

How would you recommend I solve the problem of re-using code across multiple apps?

Thanks,

Comment: "However, none of the following seem to work"?  What error are you getting?  Please be very specific on what you see, since we can't guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that you have a project called **commons** where you store all the code you want to share. And then you want to use the code of **commons** in a project called **foo**. Imagine that you have the follow directories:

```
/home/shared/commons.py
/home/tim/projects/foo.py
```

The **commons.py** have this content:

```
def say_hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

If you want to be able to import the module **commons** in your file **test.py** put in this file:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/shared/")

import commons
print commons.say_hello()
```

And it will print "Hello world!".

Comment: You almost certainly shouldn't be doing any sys.path.append in a Django project.  A better option would be to create a "common" app that you import in the standard Django way from all of your other apps.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the directory above the app is on your PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a folder in the route of your project (in which you can create the functions you want and then import them to the desired app/file) or, you can either use a app/utils.py file, the problem that I have with this one is the fact that, maybe another app that wanted to use your functions/objects from the app/utils.py will have a direct reference linked to it e.g:

```
from app.utils import my_desired_function
```

Hope it helps :)